# react-router-v4 NavLink not rerendering components

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

With react router 2, a click on a "Link" component will trigger a rerendering of components.

I'm converting my project to react router 4, using "NavLink" instead of "Link". Everything works except this : A click on a "NavLink" is not rerendering my component (updating my todos list), it only changes the link.

Is there anything I should add somewhere to make this work ?   It's working perfectly fine with react router 2 "Link".

Here's sample code :

App.js :

```
const App = ({ match: { params } }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <AddTodo />
      <VisibleTodoList filter={params.filter || 'all'} />
      <Footer />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Footer.js:

```
const Footer = () => (
  <p>
    Show:
    {" "}
    <FilterLink filter="all">
      All
    </FilterLink>
    {", "}
    <FilterLink filter="active">
      Active
    </FilterLink>
    {", "}
    <FilterLink filter="completed">
      Completed
    </FilterLink>
  </p>
);
```

Filterlink.js :

```
const FilterLink = ({ filter, children }) => {
    return (
        <NavLink
            exact
            to={filter === "all" ? "/" : `/${filter}`}
            activeStyle={{ textDecoration: "none", color: "red" }}
        >
            {children}
        </NavLink>
    );
};
```

VisibleTodoList.js :

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  return {
    todos: getVisibleTodos(
        state.todos,
        ownProps.filter
    ),
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    onTodoClick(id) {
        dispatch(toggleTodo(id))
    },
});

const VisibleTodoList = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(TodoList);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no `params` props in v4 anymore, well, not the way it used to be,

You gotta change a few things.

In your `App.js`:

```
// imports

import {withRouter} from 'react-router'

// ...

let App = ({ match }) => ( // change params to match
  return (
    <div>
      <AddTodo />
      <VisibleTodoList filter={match.params.filter || 'all'} />
      <Footer />
    </div>
  )
}

App = withRouter(App)
```

And remember if you ever wanted to add `react-redux` `connect` HOC to `App.js`, you gotta wrap `connect()` with `withRouter()`:

```
App = withRouter(connect()(App))
```

Then where you import `App`:

```
import {Router} from 'react-router'
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'
import App from './path/to/App'

// ...

<Router history={createHistory()}>
   <App />
</Router>
```

Comment: My mistake for params, I was already ok in my code. I've edited my main post.    And it's not working yet with "withRouter" "connect".  Should I try adding it to VisibleTodoList component instead?

Comment: Also, I'm using "react-router-dom" (cause react router v4), not "react-router".   It's not working this way : `const VisibleTodoList = withRouter(connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
))(TodoList);`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @kiarashws

The route needed to be passed inside a separate component :

```
const MyRoutes = () => (
    <Route path='/:filter?' component={App} />
);
render(
    <Provider store={store}>
          <Router>
              <MyRoutes/>
          </Router>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
)
```

If instead of "MyRoutes" I pass the route directly, the NavLink won't trigger the Todos update. So why the route needs to be in a separate component ?

Comment: The Redux HOC is messing up the React Router HOC. To fix it, you need to use `withRouter`.